# Bash arithmetic expression with variable

Tags: bash, variables, arithmetic-expressions

I'm writing a small bash script to treat my data.

In part of the script, I need to use the data, which exists in my raw data, to generate a new value.

However, the script I wrote does not work.

The terminal gives me the following error

")0.192500rror: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "

the value of each variable is:
inc= 0.0200000, str= -0.192500, pts= 1024,

My script is as follows:

```
for i in *.TXT; do

    inc=$(sed -n '/^#XPERCHAN/ p' $i | sed 's/[A-Z:# ]//g')
    str=$(sed -n '/^#OFFSET/ p' $i | sed 's/[A-Z:# ]//g')
    pts=$(sed -n '/^#NPOINTS/ p' $i | sed 's/[A-Z:# .]//g')
    lst=$(( ($pts-1)*$inc+$str))
    echo $lst

done
```

Please help me out here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash` only knows integers. Use `bc` or a higher programming language for floats.

```
lst=$(echo "($pts - 1) * $inc + $str" | bc)
```

**EDIT:** If your file is formatted like I think it is (`#XPERCHAN: 0.0200000`), you can do all of that in one `awk`:

```
lst=$(awk '/^#XPERCHAN/ { inc=$2 } /^#OFFSET/ { str=$2 } /^#NPOINTS/ { pts=$2 } END { print ((pts + 1) * inc + str) }' $i)
```

Comment: I used your code, it returns me the following: 
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^M
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^M
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^M

Comment: That means your file is made on Windows, and your `sed` didn't clean it up well enough. Either add `\r` to the list of the characters to filter out, or use the `awk` method (which will not pick it up in the first place).

Comment: I used your EDIT, it works perfectly! Thanks!
I still would like to know why the 1st way gave me that error.

Comment: Thanks again! I got it!

Comment: As I said, Windows. In Windows (and MSDOS), line ends with `\r\n` (CR LF, `^M^J`, lots of ways to write it.) In Linux, a line ends with `\n` (LF, `^J`), and `\r` (`^M`) is just another character. So when you delete all `A-Z:#` and spaces from it, `^M` is still there, at the end; and `bc` doesn't like it.